# Positive, monotone decreasing function, with limit in 0 equal to ∞ submultiplicative up to an factor?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, asymptotics

For $x_+ \in (0,\infty)$ let $f\colon(0,x_+] \to (0,\infty)$ be a continous differentiable function with $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0,x_+]$.
Moreover, we assume that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$$
holds.

**The question:** Does this implies that there exists a $\beta \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)f(y) \ge \beta f(xy)$ for all $x,y \in (0,x_+]$.

From my intuition this is not valid, however i am not able to derive a counter example; that function needs to be really steep in direction $x \to 0$.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \frac{a}{x^p}$ for $a, p > 0$? You can take $\beta = a$.

Comment: Why write both $(0,x_+]$ and $]0,x_+]$ in the same post?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar by accident, this has been fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is given by
$$f(x)=e^{1/x}.$$

Indeed, then $f(x)f(x)/f(xx)\to0$ as $x\downarrow0$, so that, for any real $x_+$, there is no real $\beta>0$ such that $f(x)f(y)\ge\beta f(xy)$  for all $x,y$ in $(0,x_+]$

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, i was playing around with some exponential functions but couldn't find the right arguments, thank you very much!

Comment: @maximilian43 : You are welcome.